# Finding MBS OAS in practice

Tags: mbs

I'm reading Fabozzi's Bond Markets, Analysis and Strategies, and I have a practical question about finding OAS.

The book basically says you simulate interest rate paths and take the average price of the PVs of the discounted cash flows for each interest rate path simulation.  It also says to expect around 1024 trials to converge to within a tick on the bond price.

The method is basically layed out here:
https://financetrainingcourse.com/education/2010/08/computational-finance-option-adjusted-spread-a-numerical-finance-example/

However, the link above makes the same jump as Fabozzi, where details are left out:

> The projected interest rates plus a “guess” OAS are used to discount the cash flows to determine the theoretical price. Once the price is determined under the various interest paths, the model solves of the OAS which makes the average of the theoretical prices equal the observed market price.

So you have a best guess, you run your 1024 trials (or so) to converge on a price... but then let's say the price is too high?
Do you tweak the OAS guess and then run all the trials all over again?
That seems intractable.

When I am calibrating for Z-Spread, I take the static cash flows and use a nelder-mead method to iteratively modify my Z-Spread to find the Z-Spread that matches the discounted cash flows to the observed price.

Let's say that process takes 100 iterations to find the Z-Spread.

If I did a similar method for OAS, this implies 100*1024 trials in total.

Is this actually the preferred approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run the trials again. That would be insane and you'd never guarantee easy convergence.

Take all your trials. You have cashflows and short rates. So, two matrices which are $T\times 1024$ in size. These are generated in advance.

You need to take the short rates and bump them all up by a constant OAS, generate the corresponding one-period (risky) returns. So if $CF(t_i,k)$ is the cashflow in period $t_i$ along path $k$ and $r(t_i,k)$ is the corresponding short rate, you want to compute the one-period money-market returns $\exp(-r(t_i,k)+OAS)$ and then cumulate them, i.e., take the cumulative product 
$$DF(t_j,k)=\prod_{j=1}^j \exp(-r(t_i,k)+OAS)$$, which will give you today's PV for \$1 at time $t_j$ on the $k^{th}$ path (this is the return of a money-market along that path, not really a discount factor, so the notation might be a little off)

Take the product of the $DF$ and the $CF$ and sum them to get a $$PV(k,OAS)=\sum_{i=1}^{T} DF(t_j,k,OAS) CF(t_j,k) $$ the PV for the $k^{th}$ path for that OAS, and finally, average across all paths to get $PV^{model}(OAS)=\frac{1}{1024}\sum_{k=1}^{1024} PV(k,OAS)$ as a function of OAS.

If your model price is higher than the market price, you need to adjust the OAS up, and if it's too low, you need to adjust your OAS down.

Comment: Please double-check my formulas! I really couldn't be bothered to read your book (*sorry*)! I did them from memory. I used to work in the area about 15 years back.